# Neo4j Desktop Error: PowerShell was not found

Tags: powershell, neo4j

Whenever I open my Neo4j Desktop, this error appears.

> PowerShell was not found. The application does not function correctly
> without PowerShell. It is recommended that you install PowerShell and
> make sure it is added to your path.

But when I check my user variables, I have already included the PowerShell in my path. What seems to be the problem?

[image: User Variables]

Answer (score 0):

While it might sound stupid, please check if you can see the folder: *C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0*
If not, that has to be fixed first of course.

If you can see the folder, try moving the PowerShell variable up the list, preferably to the top just for testing at least.
You could also consider adding it to the System variable.